# Cannot Decode JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Can anyone would please help me to decode this json array

```
{
    "msg": "[{\"emp_fname\":\"charmaine\",\"emp_lname\":\"romero\"},{\"emp_fname\":\"cara\",\"emp_lname\":\"delevigne\"}]",
    "count": "2"
}
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: You need to tell us if the `\"` sequences in the value of the `"msg"` property are meant to represent actual double quotation marks, or if they are meant to represent an actual backslash followed by an actual double quotation mark. In the former case, you can simply do `JSON.parse(obj.msg)`. In the latter case, the JSON is broken, and cannot be easily parsed. Are you viewing the object in the network tab, and this is the payload, or are you viewing it in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid JSON if you just delete the '\' characters and remove the outer quotes on the array:

```
{
  "msg": [
    {
      "emp_fname": "charmaine",
      "emp_lname": "romero"
    },
    {
      "emp_fname": "cara",
      "emp_lname": "delevigne"
    }
  ],
  "count": "2"
}
```

I recommend using a lint tool to debug JSON.